# How to validate multiple checkboxes

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I have three checkboxes in one row. For every checkbox I have one layout below to that which is invisible.

1) If first check box is checked, respective layout will be visible.
2) If second checkbox is checked, respective layout will be visible.
3) If third checkbox is checked, respective layout will be visible.
4) If all checkbox are checked, all layouts will be visible.

Comment: so what kind of validation are you looking for be clear your question is not at all understandable

Comment: if not checked dont show layout, of checkbox checked show layout

Comment: I have three check boxes ...If first checkbox is checked.One layout will come below to that...If 2nd is checked another layout ll be visible..if two are checked two layouts ll be visible

Comment: yes exactly @karan mer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

```
public class MySampleActivity extends Activity {
    CheckBox cb1, cb2, cb3, cb4;
    LinearLayout l1, l2, l3, l4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
        cb2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb2);
        cb3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb3);
        cb4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb4);
        l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l1);
        l2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l2);
        l3 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l3);
        l4 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.l4);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MyCheckedChangeListener(1));
        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MyCheckedChangeListener(2));
        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MyCheckedChangeListener(3));
        cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MyCheckedChangeListener(4));
    }

    public class MyCheckedChangeListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        int position;

        public MyCheckedChangeListener(int position) {
            this.position = position;
        }

        private void changeVisibility(LinearLayout l1, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                l1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                l1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            switch (position) {
                case 1:
                    changeVisibility(l1, isChecked);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    changeVisibility(l2, isChecked);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    changeVisibility(l3, isChecked);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    changeVisibility(l4, isChecked);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your checkbox is checked or not and show hide based on it like this :

```
CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cb1);
cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if (isChecked)
        {
            yourLayout.setVisibility(View.Visible);
        }
        else
        { 
            yourLayout.setVisibility(View.Gone );
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do for all like above.

Comment: @happy_ssm just add listens to all the check boxes. Each checkbox with the respective layout to it.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml layout file, give each checkbox an id (checkbox_1, checkbox_2, checkbox_3):

```
android:id="@+id/checkbox_1"
```

Same with layout elements (layout_1, layout_2, layout_3):

```
android:id="@+id/layout_1"
```

In your code, point to the elements:

```
CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox_1);
RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_1);
```

Add a check listener to each checkbox:

```
checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if (isChecked)
        {
            layout1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else
        {
            layout1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Same for the other two.

Comment: @happy_ssm In the same place you wrote the code for the first checkbox. write the code for checkbox2 just after the code for checkbox1. and checkbox3 after checkbox2.